# Print on the console the link's name

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

i have an HTML list with some link:

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="#" name="link1">link1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" name="link2">link2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" name="link3">link3</a></li>
</ul>
```

Each link has a different name.

In nodeJS, when i click the link i want to print on the console the name of the link that I clicked.

how can i do?

Comment: `node.js` is server-side. Your question is about a client-side problem. Please be more specific, and show what you've tried so far.

Comment: As far as I know, Node does not even implement the DOM API. But, how exactly can you click on a link in Node? Do you mean that the link triggers an AJAX call that's processed by Node?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this javascript code to print the name of the link

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="#" id="link1" name="link1" onclick ="console.log('link1')">link1</li>
  <li><a href="#" name="link2" onclick ="console.log('link2')">link2</li>
  <li><a href="#" name="link3" onclick ="console.log('link3')">link3</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Well, yes... But you get the information in the browser console, not in Node console.